# How to get selected option on click or change event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

HTML

```
<form name='region_filter' action='/jobseek/search_cv/' method='get'>                              
  <select id="id_region" class="" name="region">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Все</option>
    <option value="3">Донецк</option>
    <option value="2">Киев</option>
    <option value="1">Харьков</option>
  </select>   
  <input class='submit' type='button' value='adgf'/>                 
</form>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
    var selected = $('#id_region option:selected');
        console.log(selected);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/jobseek/search_cv/',
            data: {'region': selected.val()},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#category').html(data);
            },      
            error: function(textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log('sdfg');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Each click at the trigger button I got the same selected option, which loaded with page, not that what I select immediately before the click of a button. How to get actual selected option?

Comment: seems like no problems: http://jsfiddle.net/Daess/zyLeV/

Comment: What does `console.log(selected);` show an object or what ?

Comment: @Sarfraz, yes - I want to know what the option are selected on each click I did.

Comment: Not clear what it should do. The page should not submit, or at least not before the ajax call is completed...

Comment: anyway, why don't you want to use `$('#id_region').val()`?

Comment: I think your problem comes from elsewhere in your js.

Comment: Can we have a fiddle with the complete js maybe?

Comment: do you have more than one DOM item with the same id id_region?

Comment: try to remove the default selected item too. maybe that is causing problems aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you only have one select with id `id_region`.

And then try this:

```
var selectedval = $("#id_region").val();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dt8FR/

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value directly from the select element and stopping the form from submitting:

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $('#id_region').val(); 
    console.log(val); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '/jobseek/search_cv/', 
        data: {'region': val}, 
        dataType: 'html', 
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#category').html(data); 
        },       
        error: function(textStatus, jqXHR){ 
            console.log('sdfg'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dont change your selected item.
You ask him to go to the val of your selected item, which is the first item in your list.

This attribute will not get removed and added to the current picked item.
At least not on jsfiddle where I quickly copy pasted it.

Is there code that you didnt post or is this everything?

Added extra code example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#id_region').change(function(){
        var option = $(this).val();
        $('option:selected', 'select').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#id_region option[value=' + option +']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });

    $('.submit').click(function(){
    alert($('#id_region option:selected').val());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97PY6/